# Error creating linear regression model in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, lm

I am creating a number of objects, each a `lm` model
This is an example with `iris`:

```
di = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
for (v in di){
  model = lm (v ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris)
  modname = paste0("model_", v)
  assign(modname, model)
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = v ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Petal.Length')
```

The models work correctly, despite `NA`, in the real data, when they are created separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your expression v is just a string.  You need to convert it to a formula.  See the `formula()` function.

```
di = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
for (v in di){
   model = lm (formula(paste(v, " ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width")), data = iris)
   modname = paste0("model_", v)
   assign(modname, model)
}
```

Word of advice it is generally a poor practice to modify the global environment using the `assign()` function.  Try appending the model onto a list, that way all of the models are grouped together in one data structure.

Such as this:

```
answer <- lapply (setNames(di, di), function(v) {
   lm (formula(paste(v, " ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width")), data = iris)
})
answer
```